# Compare a NSArray with NSString in swift?

Tags: arrays, string, swift, comparison

I have a array with some words and I want to check whether these words exist in my string or not. Here is the sample code

```
var array: NSArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

var Str: NSString = "one example of my string"
```

Now one exist in the string, but I am not able to compare them. How to get that one compared?

Comment: check the arraycontains method .

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this,

```
var array: NSArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

var Str: NSString = "one example of my string"

let filteredString = Str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").filter { a in
    return array.containsObject(a)
}
print(filteredString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSString.containsString(string) method:

```
let Str : NSString = "This is one string"
let array : [NSString] = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

for word in array {
    print("is \(word) mentioned in string? : \(Str.containsString(word as String))" )
}
```

with output:

- *is one mentioned in string? : true*
- *is two mentioned in string? : false*
- *is three mentioned in string? : false*
- *is four mentioned in string? : false*

Answer (score 0):

To use a method if you have different arrays of strings to check you can do it like that:

```
var array: NSArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

var str: NSString = "one example of my string"

func checkIfStringOfArrayExists(arrayOfString: NSArray, inString string: NSString) -> Bool {
    for element in array where str.containsString(element as! String) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

checkIfStringOfArrayExists(array, inString: str) // true
```

Comment: Thanks, I find this option an easy one. Because I can do my stuff now.

Answer (score 0):

If simple `Bool` result is what you need:

```
array.contains{ string.containsString(String($0)) } // true
```

However, I would suggest working with Swift's `Array` and `String` value types instead and then extending `String` as follows:

```
public extension String {

    public func containsAny(strings: [String]) -> Bool {
        return strings.contains{ containsString($0) }
    }
}

let strings = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
let string = "one example of my string"

string.containsAny(strings) // true
```